# Xamarin File Handling Documentation - SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData doesn't exist

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

[Documentation for Xamarin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/files?tabs=vswin#saving-and-loading-files) says you can read a text file using the below:

```
File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "score.txt"))
```

"score.txt" being a text file in my solution, however, when compiling and executing that code the file cannot be found:

[image: FileNotFoundException]

I can successfully read the text file in my solution with this:

```
using (var stream = await FileSystem.OpenAppPackageFileAsync("score.txt"))
using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
```

However I can't use a stream reader as I need to read the file when the app opens so it cannot be asynchronous.

What am I doing wrong or is the documentation wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "score.txt"))

`LocalApplicationData` is not the location of the native bundled assets. You need to copy it first out of the read only app bundle.

> However I can't use a stream reader as I need to read the file when the app opens so it cannot be asynchronous.

You can do this in multiple areas change to the `OnStart` override in your Forms' Application subclass (typically `App`) to allow `await`

```
protected async override void OnStart()
{
   ...
```

You could also do this in first page `OnAppearing` override:

```
protected async override void OnAppearing()
{
   ...
```

Xamarin.Essentials `OpenAppPackageFileAsync` returns a stream to a "native" Android Asset or iOS bundle resource, etc.. so you will need copy your `score.txt` file into the native projects

#### Android:

Add/copy the `score.txt` to your Xamarin.Android project Assets with a build action of `AndroidResource`

[image]

#### iOS:

Add/copy the `score.txt` to your Xamarin.iOS projects Resources (technically anywhere, but for organization Resources works well) with a build action of `BundleResource`

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. I was missing the addition of async to the subclass OnAppearing(). I thought I had already tried that but guess I got the syntax wrong and misdiagnosed the issue.